# Angular video not autoplaying in chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, html5-video

I have a background video for the homepage of my Angular application, it's supposed to autoplay yet the autoplay is working in Safari and Firefox but not Chrome.

I have followed Chrome's policy of muting the video and the autoplay is still not working.

I have also tried hard-refreshing and opening in an incognito window to make sure it isn't the cache.

```
<video onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" playsinline autoplay muted loop class="fade-video">
    <source src="assets/video/homepagevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

I have also added `onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"` which was another solution I found on StackOverflow, but still, no luck.

Comment: Use ViewChild to select the video tag and trigger the play function.

Comment: @User9123 As a test... **(1)** Enable `controls` on your video tag, then check if the video's load bar is just taking a long time to reach fully loaded. Slow loading progress will give you _autoPlay_ later on... **(2)** What happens when you immediately press the _Play_ button when the page is loaded? **(3)** (when using the **Inspect** menu option in Chrome browser) What is the **console** saying about any errors with loading or playing the file?